# WPF Warning with VSTS: Different checksum values given for '*.g.cs' Files

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio 2008 Team System, this is my warning:

```
Different checksum values given for '<some folder>' ...\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\...
\Debug\...\SomeFile.g.cs
```

The offending line in the `SomeFile.g.cs` file is:

```
#pragma checksum "..\..\..\..\..\..\...\SomeFile.xaml" "{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}" "A18BC47B27EC4695C69B69F1831E3225"
```

I deleted *all* of the `*.g.cs` files in the Solution and rebuilt and *all* of the warnings came back. What the hell is this?

Comment: Do you by chance have some files being generated with really long paths?  This warning should mean that there are two files with the same name and Visual Studio can't determine which one to debug from, but it is possible that it truncates the path at a certain point when comparing them to each other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like Visual Studio doesn't handle very long paths correctly when generating GUIDs.  I confirmed this by adding two different files into a long path and reproduced the behavior you are seeing.  If you look in the offending SomeFile.g.cs files you will notice that the guids for the two files are the same.  Apparently Visual Studio only checks the first *x* characters of the file path when generating this GUID.

```
C:\Users\Developer\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\obj\Debug\LongFolderNameLongFolderNameLongFolderName\LongFolderNameLongFolderNameLongFolderName\LongFolderNameLongFolderNameLongFolderName\SomeFileName1.g.cs(1,1): warning CS1697: Different checksum values given for 'c:\Users\Developer\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\LongFolderNameLo'
C:\Users\Developer\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\obj\Debug\LongFolderNameLongFolderNameLongFolderName\LongFolderNameLongFolderNameLongFolderName\LongFolderNameLongFolderNameLongFolderName\SomeFileName2.g.cs(1,1): (Related location)
```

From the .g.cs files:

```
#pragma checksum "..\<snipped>\SomeFileName1.xaml" "{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}" "F21D94943016E57893CEB405BE12ADEA"
#pragma checksum "..\<snipped>\SomeFileName2.xaml" "{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}" "C67F2F8C841E2C338E5FCDC5037E8454"
```

As for a solution, I guess you could either shorten your paths or (more likely) ignore these warnings. :)

Comment: I'll confirm it on my end but this feels like the right solution!

Comment: Confirmed! This *is* the solution!

Comment: Has this been raised with Microsoft?

Comment: Seems like this issue is still present in .net 4.5.2 . The connect-feedback entry 404s ("page not found"). There's still some info to be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/406d5b67-a7af-4d59-97ad-21e701d63192/questions-regarding-error-cs1697-different-checksum-values-given-for-path-to-file?forum=csharplanguage).